# $X,Y$ linear spaces - reasoning about linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$X,Y$ are linear subspaces, $f:X\to Y$ and $x_1,...,x_n$ is base of spaces $X$.  Then:
a. vector system $f(x_1),...,f(x_n)$ is linearly independent
b. vector system $f(x_1),...,f(x_n)$ spans space $Y$.
c. if $f$ is epimorphism then $\dim(Y)\le n$

b.  Is not true - let's consider example:
$X=\mathbb{R}^2$
$Y=\mathbb{R}^3$
$\dim(span(f([0,1],[1,0])) \le 2 < \dim(Y)$

a. false,  $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^2$  $f([x_1, x_2])=[x_1+x_2, x_1+x_2]$
$f([1,0]) = [1,1]$
$f([0,1]) = [1,1]$
system of vectors $([1,1], [1,1])$ is not linearly independent.

c. It seems to be false, but I can't prove it. Could you help me ?

Comment: $\;f\;$ is just a function, or is it a linear map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image of $T$ is the following set:

$\{T(x)| x\in X\}$, of course, if $x_1,x_2\dots x_n$ is a basis this set is also:

$\{T(a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\dots + a_nx_n)|a_1,a_2\dots a_n\in \mathbb R\}$, by linearity this is:

$\{a_1T(x_1)+a_2T(x_2)+\dots a_nT(x_n)|a_1,a_2\dots a_n\in \mathbb R\}=span\{T(x_1),T(x_2)\dots T(x_n)\}$.

If $T$ is an epimorphism then the image of $T$ is $Y$.

Therefore $Y$ is spanned by the $n$ vectors $T(x_1),T(x_2)\dots T(x_n)$, so the dimension of $Y$ is at most $n$.

---

Shorter answer: If $x_1,x_2\dots x_n$ is a basis for $X$ then $\dim(X)=n$.

Notice that $\dim(Y)=\dim(Im(T))=\dim(X)-\dim(\ker(T))\leq n$

Comment: Assuming  your $\;T\;$ is the OP's $\;f\;$ and it is a linear map (otherwise who knows what Ker$\,T\;$ is, say...), the first equality in your last line is wrong *unless* $\;T=f\;$ is an epimorphism. Perhaps you're addressing (c) in the OP's question?

Comment: Tell me please, what is whole fact and what is fact depends on epimorphism ? $\dim(Y) = \dim(Im(T)) + \dim(\ker(T)) $   Is it always that $Im(T) = span(T(x_1),...,T(x_n))$ where $x_1, ..., x_n$ is base.

Comment: tell me, if a. and b. are ok?

Comment: Yes, I am proving $c$ is true @DonAntonio . And yes, $a$ and $b$ are true, regards.